# Python Serial Port and MySQLdb

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino, mysql-python

I am currently working on a project to send data from arduino to MySQL through python and serial port.

As arduino will send data to Python on a interval of 10sec, Which python code will allow me to send data to mysqldb only when python detects a string of data on serial port and afterwhich, delete the data on serial port after sending to MySQLdb.

I have tried the ser.flush () commands for the deleting data part but to no avail.

Comment: You should really separate the two tasks, and understand each to make sure they are working independent of each other. Then integrate.

Comment: Why do you want to delete serial port data? As soon as you call read() the data is transferred to your application buffer and is no longer available neither in UART/driver nor pyserial stack (the buffer pointer moves).